# Deleting <null> inside an NSMutableDictionary inside an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I been searching for a while now on how to remove nil, null,  values here and into google are tried all what i saw but im always having an exception which says selector not imcompatible.
This is my Array and NSMutableArray with an NSMutableDictionary

```
Array Value = (
        {
           "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Laptop";
           "sub_name" = Laptop;
        },
        {
           "sub_desc" = "sub cat description of Printers";
           "sub_name" = Printers;
        },
           "<null>",
           "<null>",
           "<null>",
           "<null>"
)
```

and im trying to remove the  values, any ideas?

my segue goes like this

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

        ChildTableViewController *myNextPage = [segue destinationViewController];
        if ([myNextPage isKindOfClass:[ChildTableViewController class]]){  
            NSString *key = [[[parsedData listPopulated]objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
            myNextPage.childData = [[parsedData childPopulated]valueForKey:key]; 
        }
    }
}
```

and childData is an NSMutableArray in my Child View Controller and also childPopulated is an NSMutableArray where Im inserting NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: You don't need to rename questions as [SOLVED], you should accept an answer by clicking one of the little ticks next to the best answer

Comment: But i solved it myself, and also i wouldn't click an answer that would be right coz that would be wrong. But i'll put that in mind next time.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question and answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`[NSMutableArray removeObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObject%3a):

> Removes all occurrences in the array of a given object.

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;
[array removeObject:@"<null>"];
```

Note: your array contains a mix of dictionary and strings objects; not just dictionary objects.

Comment: i tried this already, and tried again to give the exception xD

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x718ff10'

Comment: @AceMunim That means `array` isn't an `NSMutableArray`, it's an `NSArray`.  Make it mutable **before** trying to mutate it...

Comment: im looking at all my code there's isn't even one NSArray, its all MutableArray and MutableDictionaries

Comment: @AceMunim Well somewhere along the line you are calling `removeObject` on an `NSArray` object.  If you cannot find it then edit your question and post the relevant code.

Comment: when i used your code that the time im calling removeObject, and before that im not calling that code anywhere. And btw that array data im getting from the parent view controller and passed it on my child view controller. That might help too

Comment: @AceMunim Sorry I cannot help further without seeing the code.  Rest assured though, you are operating on an `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`, which means you cannot remove anything until that changes.

Comment: i've inserted my segue code and included some info hope it'll help

Comment: <null> could be an NSNull instance, try [array removeObject:[NSNull null]];

Comment: @AceMunim OK, so add the following (after `myNextPage.childData = ...`) to that code and tell me what it says: `NSLog("childData=%@", NSStringFromClass([myNextPage.childData class]));`;

Comment: this is the output -->   childData=__NSArrayI
why is there an NSArray even tho im not using it :(

Comment: @AceMunim: It does not matter how you declare your variable. `NSJSONSerialization` by default returns *immutable* arrays/dictionaries, unless you use the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option.

Comment: @AceMunim Yes. Even if you change it to a mutable array, it won't affect anything else as it will just be thrown away anyway.  If you want class B to modify a collection in class A, then you need to pass a reference to the original collection, not a copy.

Comment: @trojanfoe ohh i see, thanx for that one, but Im also new about this and may i know what do you mean by passing a reference to the original collection? Does it mean where im parsing i need to save the data into another class and access that.

Comment: @AceMunim I mean pass the complete object (i.e `[otherClass doThingToMyCollection:array]`).

Comment: i been thinking but couldnt figure out what u said. kinda too complex for a new guy like me. The object that i used in my parser is NSMutableArray childPopulated, do it mean that?

Comment: thats the mutable array in my parser where i add values to from the didEndElement from NSXMLParser delegate.

Comment: @AceMunim Sorry but this discussion is way off topic now.  You are best starting a new question on how to get the mutable array into another class so that it can be modified.

Comment: @trojanfoe okiez, and thanx a bunch, will ask question maybe tomorrow again, its late this time here now.

Answer (score 2):

This code should o it:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet;
for (NSUinteger i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    if (![array[i] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        [indexSet addIndex:i]
    }
}
array = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexSet]
```

If you want to remove objects that are the string *null* then:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet;
for (NSUinteger i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    if ([array[i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [array[i] isEqualToString:@"<null>") {
        [indexSet addIndex:i]
    }
}
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet]
```

Comment: The null objects are `NSString`'s containing the text `@"<null>"`, not `NSNull` objects.

Comment: He says: "I been searching for a while now on how to remove nil, null, values" he doesn't say strings containing the word "null". However if the case is removing objects that are the string "null" you answer is correct.

Comment: Did you look at the (JSON) representation of the array he posted?

Comment: Yes. And it is a JSON representation. Another thnig is how this JSON object gest converted into a NSMutableArray. If "<null>" gets converted to @"<null>" you are right. Anyway I have updated my answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The NSLog output of `@[[NSNull null], @"<null>"]` is `"<null>", "<null>"`. It is impossible to distinguish the string and the null-object.

Comment: Thanks martin!! That is why two different people thought of two differnet objects, [NSNull null] and @"<null>". Good point.

Comment: This is a frustrating thing.  NSLog of an NSNull produces `<null>` -- no quotes -- but NSLog of an *array* containing an NSNull produces `"<null>"`.  It would sure be nice if `description` were consistent.

Comment: Totally agree, it is confusing.